# How to formally prove $\forall x: x11=x$ in the theory of groups.

Tags: group-theory, logic, proof-theory, formal-proofs

Def 1: $M$ is a $\underline{theory}$, if it is a collection of first order statements.

Def 2: Given theory $M$ and first order statement $\phi$, then $M$ can $\underline{prove}$ $\phi$ if, starting with some statements $m_0,m_1,...,m_n \in M$ and following the rules of deduction we arrive at $\phi$.

Def 3: Given a constant symbol 1, the $\underline{theory \ of \ groups}$ is:

Identity
$$\forall x  : x1=x $$

Associativity
$$\forall x,y,z: (xy)z=x(yz) $$

Inverses
$$\forall x : x^{-1} x = x x^{-1} = 1 $$ 
$$ $$

$$Updated \  Proof \ Attempt: $$

\begin{align*}
1. \  \forall x : x1=x&  \ \ \ Identity  \\
2. \  \forall x: x1=x \Rightarrow \ y1=y& \ \ \ Universal \ Instantiation \ (with \ x=y) \\
3. \  \forall x: x1=x \Rightarrow \ (y1)1=y1& \ \ \ Universal \ Instantiation \ (with \ x=y1) \\
 4. \ y1=y& \ \ \ 1,2, \ Modus \ Ponens \\
 5. \ (y1)1=y1& \ \ \ 1,3, \ Modus \ Ponens \\
 6. \ (y1)1=y& \ \ \ 4,5, \ Transitivity \\
 7. \forall x : (x1)1 = x& \ \ \ 2-6, \ Universal \ Generalization \ (y \ was \ arbitrary)
\end{align*}

Comment: Check your title?

Comment: Hint: also instantiate 'Identity' with $y1$.

Comment: The proof attempt seems reasonable to me now.   Of course there can be tiny differences between proof systems, but your argument has all the key points.

Answer (score 4):

Almost always,$^*$ the way to produce a formal proof is to first produce a very detailed informal proof, and then step-by-step convert it into your specific proof calculus *(there are many different notions of formal proof for first-order logic; they're all ultimately equivalent, but they have different details, and a complete answer to your question is impossible without knowing your specific system)*.

An informal proof of $\forall x[(x1)1=x]$ goes as follows:

- For all $z$, $z1=z$ from the group axioms.
- In particular, this implies $(x1)1=x1$ (applying the above with $z=x1$).
- Separately, this implies $x1=x$ (applying the first bullet with $z=x$).
- Putting these together, we get $(x1)1=x1$.

Now it should be clear what you're going to want to do here: you need to do a couple instantiations, and then compose equalities. Can you see how to do this in your specific proof calculus?

---

There are exceptions, when the statement in question is "obvious" but the proof system is meaningfully weak. For example, intuitively we should be able to combine a proof of $B$ from $A$ and a proof of $C$ from $B$ to get a proof of $C$ from $A$; however, depending on what proof calculus you use [this turns out to be more complicated than it sounds](https://www.jstor.org/stable/30226313?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) (even though it does work in the end). And these are not always pathological cases - indeed, the issue in the previous sentence (["cut elimination"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut-elimination_theorem)) is of fundamental importance in mathematical logic, specifically proof theory.

However, this is not the situation you're in here.

Comment: so

$$ 1. \  \forall x : x1=x   \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ Identity $$
$$ 2. \  \forall x: x1=x \Rightarrow (y1)1=y1  \ \ \ Universal \ Instantiation$$
$$ 3. (y1)1=y1  \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 1,2, \ modus \ ponens $$
$$ 3. (y1)1=y  \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ Identity $$

am I on the right track...?

Comment: I updated my proof attempt in the original post, does it look any better?